# How to quickly return to the place where I started Quick Find jumping in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

In Visual Studio 2005, when I press Ctrl+F and start finding a text, particularly in the Current Document, I want to be able to quickly undo all the subsequent jumps when I saw what I was looking for, and simply return the cursor to the place where it was when I pressed Ctrl+F. Now I have to manually scroll to the place, and that's pretty annoying.

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, there is Ctrl+minus functionality: it returns your cursor to the previous navigation point. Works after "Go to definition" as well as after "Quick Find".

Hope this helps other poor souls :)